# What is the circumference (arc length) of $x^4 + x^2 + y^4 + y^2 = 2$?

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

Consider

$$x^4 + x^2 + y^4 + y^2 = 2$$

It is a smooth non-intersecting circle like curve in the plane.

A bit like a Hyperellipse.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

What is the circumference (arc length) of $x^4 + x^2 + y^4 + y^2 = 2$ ?

[Wolfram|Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E4%2By%5E2%3D2)

Comment: you want a name? a picture?

Comment: I think he wants the arc length.

Comment: I was not sure about circumference, but I looked it up. Indeed it is arc length. But my terminology is correct too.

Comment: would you be so nice and share your ideas...

Comment: What ideas ? I just wonder about it. AGAIN a close vote !?!? :s

Comment: For some more info on this particular shape, [see here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squircle.html)

Comment: @user170231 that is a bit different, not ?

Comment: @mick You're right, I had the incorrect notion that completing the square would give you a shifted squircle.

Answer (score 5):

In polar coordinates: $$r^4\cos^4t+r^2\cos^2t+r^4\sin^4t+r^2\sin^2t=2$$
$$r^4\left(\cos^4t+\sin^4t\right)+r^2-2=0$$
$$r^2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8\left(\cos^4t+\sin^4t\right)}}{2\left(\cos^4t+\sin^4t\right)}$$

Now the arc length for polar coordinates is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$ So it appears you have a challenging integral to compute, and you may need to resort to an approximation technique.

---

Note $$4r^3\left(\cos^4t+\sin^4t\right)\frac{dr}{dt}+r^4\cdot4\left(-\cos^3t\sin t+\sin^3t\cos t\right)+2r\frac{dr}{dt}=0$$
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{2r^3\sin t\cos t\left(\cos^2t-\sin^2t\right)}{2r^2\left(\cos^4t+\sin^4t\right)+1}=\frac{2r^3\sin t\cos t\left(\cos^2t-\sin^2t\right)}{\sqrt{1+8\left(\cos^4t+\sin^4t\right)}}$$
$$\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{4r^6\sin^2 t\cos^2 t\left(\cos^2t-\sin^2t\right)^2}{1+8\left(\cos^4t+\sin^4t\right)}$$

You can either use this to try to conquer the integral, or you can use this to help with an approximation technique like say Simpson's Rule (where it would be wise to integrate from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and octuple the result.)

Using Simpson, with $n=2$ over $[0,\pi/4]$ and then octuple: $$8\cdot\frac{\pi}{24}\left(1+4\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{7}}{3/2}+\frac1{28}\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt7}{3/2}\right)^3}+\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{5}}\right)\approx6.6923\ldots$$ which is within $0.16\%$ of Robert's Maple decimal output.

Comment: Converting to polar was my first try, but then I saw that integral. Ew.

Comment: Cartesian is no better.

Answer (score 3):

Using the polar form, Maple evaluates the integral to 30 digits as
$6.68187645290337621429065046080$.  The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) and Maple's **identify** function both come up with nothing.

I'd guess that the probability of this having a "closed form" solution is rather small.

Answer (score 0):

Easy estimation: $2\pi = 6.28\ldots \le s \le 8$.
$$
u = x^2 + 1/2 \Rightarrow u^2 = x^4 + x^2 + 1/4 \\
v = y^2 + 1/2 \Rightarrow v^2 = y^4 + y^2 + 1/4
$$
Then 
$$
r^2 = (\sqrt{2+1/2})^2 = u^2 + v^2 = x^4 + x^2 + y^4 + y^2 + 1/2 \iff \\
2 = x^4 + x^2 + y^4 + y^2 \quad (*)
$$
So the transformed curve is a circle in the $u$-$v$-plane with radius $r = \sqrt{5/2}$ and has the known arc length $S = \pi \sqrt{10}$.
I looked for a way to transform this arc length into the wanted arc length $s$, but had no success.

For the upper half of the curve we get:
\begin{align}
v &= \sqrt{r^2 - u^2} \iff \\
y^2 + 1/2 &= \sqrt{9/4 - x^2 - x^4} \iff \\
y &= \sqrt{\sqrt{9/4 - x^2 -x^4} - 1/2} \quad (**) \\
\end{align}

This leads to the derivative
\begin{align}
y' &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sqrt{9/4 - x^2 -x^4} - 1/2}} 
\frac{-2x-4x^3}{2\sqrt{9/4 - x^2 -x^4}} \\
&= - \frac{\sqrt{2}\,x\,(1 + 2x^2)}{\sqrt{\left(9 - 4x^2(1+x^2)\right)
\left(\sqrt{9 - 4x^2(1+x^2)} - 1\right)}}
\end{align}
The arc length is
\begin{align}
s &= 4 \int\limits_0^1\sqrt{1 + (y')^2} \, dx \\
  &= 4 \int\limits_0^1\sqrt{1 + \frac{2\,x^2\,(1 + 2x^2)^2}{\left(9 - 4x^2(1+x^2)\right)
\left(\sqrt{9 - 4x^2(1+x^2)} - 1\right)}} \, dx \\
&= 6.68188
\end{align}
where the rounded numerical value was obtained from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*%20int%20sqrt%281%2B%282*x%5E2*%281%2B2*x%5E2%29%5E2%29%2F%28%289-4*x%5E2*%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29*%28sqrt%289-4*x%5E2*%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29-1%29%29%29%20dx%20from%200%20to%201).

An alternative query using the simpler equation $(**)$ is [this](http://wolfr.am/87xCbmAE). The result has to be multiplied by $4$ however.

**Addendum**

Alex Jordan pointed out that $y' \to -\infty$ for $x \to 1$, see [WA plot](http://wolfr.am/87zRUV3L). So we go only for the first 1/8 of the arc, were there is a point $(\xi,\xi)$:
$$
2 = \xi^4 + \xi^2 + \xi^4 + \xi^2 = 2\xi^2(\xi^2+1) \iff \\
1 = \xi^4 + \xi^2 = (\xi^2 + 1/2) - 1/4 \Rightarrow \\
\xi = \sqrt{(\sqrt{5} - 1)/2} = \sqrt{\varphi - 1} = 0.78615\ldots
$$
where $\varphi = 1.618\ldots$ is the golden ratio.

This leads to
\begin{align}
s &= 8 \int\limits_0^\xi\sqrt{1 + (y')^2} \, dx \\
  &= 8 \int\limits_0^\xi\sqrt{1 + \frac{2\,x^2\,(1 + 2x^2)^2}{\left(9 - 4x^2(1+x^2)\right)
\left(\sqrt{9 - 4x^2(1+x^2)} - 1\right)}} \, dx \\
\end{align}
New query: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8*%20int%20sqrt%281%2B%282*x%5E2*%281%2B2*x%5E2%29%5E2%29%2F%28%289-4*x%5E2*%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29*%28sqrt%289-4*x%5E2*%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29-1%29%29%29%20dx%20from%200%20to%20sqrt%28%28sqrt%285%29-1%29%2F2%29)

Comment: A comment on numerical efficiency: If numerically integrating using Cartesian coordinates, the software will have an easier time getting more accurate results faster if you can avoid integrating near places where $y'$ blows up. So here, there is a positive $x$-value $c=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}$ where the line $y=x$ intersects the curve. And by symmetry, $4\int_{x=-c}^{x=c}$ will also give the length, but avoid the area near $x=1$ where $y'$ blows up. Integrating over this region will keep $y'$ bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first rewrite the curve in the hope to perhaps parametrize it.

\begin{align*}
x^4+x^2+y^4+y^2=2\iff{}&\left(x^2+\frac12\right)^2+\left(y^2+\frac12\right)^2-\frac12=2\iff{} \\
{}\iff{}&\frac25\left(x^2+\frac12\right)^2+\frac25\left(y^2+\frac12\right)^2=1.
\end{align*}

So we must have $t$ such that:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\sqrt{\frac25}\left(x^2+\frac12\right)=\cos t \\
\sqrt{\frac25}\left(y^2+\frac12\right)=\sin t \\
\end{array}\right.
\iff
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
x^2=-\frac12+\sqrt{\frac52}\cos t \\
y^2=-\frac12+\sqrt{\frac52}\sin t \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Split a couple of cases depending on sign of $x,y$ (4 cases, I should think), then calculate the integrals of:

$$\gamma(t)=\left(\pm\sqrt{-\frac12+\sqrt{\frac52}\cos t},\pm\sqrt{-\frac12+\sqrt{\frac52}\sin t}\right)$$

with signs depending on the cases, sum them, and you're done.