# Numerical approximation of Lamé curve perimeter for $n >2$

Tags: calculus, approximation, plane-curves, arc-length

What is the numerical approximation for a [Lamé Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse)?

This question: [Arc length of the squircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576115/arc-length-of-the-squircle/2176414#2176414) seems to be related, but doesn't provide an answer to the case where $a \neq b$, nor the limit that $n > 2$.

Mainly as I'm trying to figure out how the [calculator here might work](https://www.had2know.org/academics/lame-curve-area-perimeter-superellipse-calculator.html) (i.e. it doesn't need to be exactly how they work, but should be a close enough approximation).

I've looked at [What is the circumference (arc length) of $x^4 + x^2 + y^4 + y^2 = 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521461/what-is-the-circumference-arc-length-of-x4-x2-y4-y2-2) and tried to [plot a superellipse](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28a*cos%28theta%29%29%5E%28n%2F%28n-1%29%29%2B%28b*sin%28theta%29%29%5E%28n%2F%28n-1%29%29%3Dr%5E%28n%2F%28n-1%29%29) then once I am sure the formula is correct I could get Wolfram Alpha to do the heavy lifting of integrating it, but the website seems to hang.

How can I approximate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is precisely how the website's calculator works:
$\newcommand{\peri}{\bbox[#E4E6E8,1px]{\textsf{Perimeter}}}
\newcommand{\ans}{\bbox[#E4E6E8]{\textsf{anss}}}$

### Discovery

If you View Source and search for the button label `Calculate` you will find
 `<td align="center" rowspan="3"><input type="button" onclick="lame(this.form)" value="Calculate" style="margin-top:2px"><br>`. Where is this `lame(...)` defined? After poking around I discovered that this is hidden in `drop-ads.js`. (Aside: is this file for advertisements? why is user-code here...?)
[image]

The full code for `lame(...)` is

```
function lame(form) {
a=eval(form.a.value);b=eval(form.b.value);n=eval(form.n.value);
var d=eval(Math.PI/1000000);
var sum=eval(0);
var i=eval(0);
while (i<250000) {
sum=sum
    +Math.sin(i*Math.PI/500000+d)
    *Math.cos(i*Math.PI/500000+d)
    *Math.sqrt(a*a*Math.pow(Math.cos(i*Math.PI/500000+d),4/n)
               /Math.pow(Math.cos(i*Math.PI/500000+d),4)
    +b*b*Math.pow(Math.sin(i*Math.PI/500000+d),4/n)
               /Math.pow(Math.sin(i*Math.PI/500000+d),4));
i=i+1; 
}
function adj(x) {
if (x<3) {c=1;}
if (x>=3&&x<4) {c=1.00007;}
if (x>=4&&x<5) {c=1.0005;}
if (x>=5) {c=1.002;}
return c;}
var zum=eval(0);
var j=eval(0);
while (j<250000) {
zum=zum+Math.pow(1-Math.pow(j/250000+1/500000,n),(1/n));
j=j+1;}
ansss=4*a*b*zum/250000;
anss=adj(n)*sum*Math.PI*4/(250000*n);
form.quote.value="Area = "+Math.round(1000*ansss)/1000+"\n"+"Perimeter = "+Math.ceil(1000*anss)/1000;}
```

### Translating from `javascript` to $math$

The relevant part of the output is given by `Math.ceil(1000*anss)/1000;}`, i.e. $\frac1{1000}{\lceil 1000\,  \ans \rceil}$. This is a rounding up to 4 decimal points of `anss=adj(n)*sum*Math.PI*4/(250000*n)`. What exactly though is `anss`?

`adj(n)` is a small fudge factor that was probably empirically determined. But the remaining bit, expressed in mathematical notation is as follows: set $N=250000$. Then
\begin{align}
&\ans =\\& \frac{4\pi}{Nn}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}2\tfrac iN+\tfrac\pi{4N}\right)\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}2\tfrac iN+\tfrac\pi{4N}\right) \sqrt{a^2\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}2\tfrac iN+\tfrac\pi{4N}\right)^{\frac4n-4} + b^2\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}2\tfrac iN+\tfrac\pi{4N}\right)^{\frac4n-4} } 
\end{align}

This is a Riemann sum (with tags $\pi i/2N + \pi/4N$ and uniform mesh size $\pi/2N$) for the integral
\begin{align}
  &\frac{4\pi}n \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x/2) \cos(\pi x/2) \sqrt{a^2\sin^{4/n-4}(\pi x/2) + b^2\cos^{4/n-4}(\pi x/2)} dx 
\\&= 4\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac2n\sin t \cos t \sqrt{a^2 \sin^{4/n-4}t+b^2\cos^{4/n-4}t } \ dt 
\end{align}
which is precisely the arc-length integral  (using symmetry across both axes to absorb the $4$)
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} |\gamma'(t)|\ dt, \quad \gamma(t) = \binom{a \lvert\sin t|^{2/n-1}\sin t}{b\lvert \cos t|^{2/n-1}\cos t},$$ where $\big|\binom{v_1}{v_2}\big|=\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}$ denotes the Euclidean norm, and for $t\in[0,\pi/2]$, $$\gamma'(t) = \frac2n\sin t\cos t\binom{a \sin^{2/n-2}t}{-b\cos^{2/n-2}t} . $$

### Visualisation of arclength integrand and Riemann sums

For $n>2$, the integrand near $t=0$ behaves like $t^{-1+2/n}$, from $\sin t\sim t$. Near $t=\pi/2$ the same happens using $\cos t \sim \pi/2-t$. This is not a bounded function (which explains why the tags cannot be the left or right endpoints of the mesh), so the Riemann sum (which approximates using a bounded step function) is likely not so accurate. [See the behavior](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1tilw06tef) near $x=0,\pi/2$:
[image]
Intuitively the error from the tails should be like the bound from [Speed of convergence of a Riemann sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514492/speed-of-convergence-of-a-riemann-sum), i.e.
$$  \int_0^{2\pi} |\gamma'(t)|\ dt = \ans + O(N^{-2/n})$$
Which might explain why some sort of fudge-factor was used; even with the huge $N=250000$, $N^{-2/10} \approx 0.083,$ so this probably isn't enough for 4 decimal points.

Comment: (A more careful analysis at the boundary would likely do better than a fudge factor)

Comment: That's awesome! I should have thought to poke about at the javascript myself, although I would have struggled to convert it to maths! Now I need to figure out how to make this work in Google Sheets ::face-palm::

Comment: @AncientSwordRage you're welcome! I noticed that I didn't save the desmos graph correctly, so I redid the graph, and then also added a calculator which can go to higher precision than the linked page (just change the value of $K$). Though I have no idea how to do this in Google Sheets. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If we have the parametrisation
$$x=a \cos ^{\frac{2}{n}}(t) \qquad \text{and} \qquad y=b \sin ^{\frac{2}{n}}(t)$$ the arc length is given,before any simplification by
$$L_n=4\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{\frac{4 a^2 \sin ^2(t) \cos ^{\frac{4}{n}-2}(t)+4 b^2 \cos ^2(t) \sin   ^{\frac{4}{n}-2}(t)}{n^2}} \,dt$$ To simplify it; let $b^2=k a^2$
$$L_n=\frac {8a}n\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2}\csc (t) \sec (t) \sqrt{\sin ^4(t) \cos^{\frac{4}{n}}(t)+k \cos ^4(t) \sin ^{\frac{4}{n}}(t)}\,dt$$

I do not think that, for $k \neq 1$, we could have closed forms for $K_n=\frac{n L_n}{8a}$.

For $k=1$, we have already very nasty expressions in terms of Meijer G-functions. So, I shall just give the numerical values for $\frac {L_n}a$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \frac {L_n}a \\
 2 & 6.283185307 \\
 3 & 6.744993140 \\
 4 & 7.017697944 \\
 5 & 7.194443066 \\
 6 & 7.317726359 \\
 7 & 7.408459373 \\
 8 & 7.477973847 \\
 9 & 7.532910247 \\
 10 & 7.577407935 \\
 11 & 7.614177499 \\
 12 & 7.645065791 \\
 13 & 7.671372121 \\
 14 & 7.694034284 \\
 15 & 7.713742831 \\
 16 & 7.731014058 \\
 17 & 7.746238338 \\
 18 & 7.759713239 \\
 19 & 7.771666925 \\
 20 & 7.782275154
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $n \gt 20$, I start having numerical problems.

Now, for $k\neq 1$, only numerical results. I shall give the results for a few values of $n$ and $k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
n & k=0.50 & k=0.75 & k=1.00 & k=1.25 & k=1.50 \\
 2 & 5.40258 & 5.86985 & 6.28319 & 6.65917 & 7.00709 \\
 3 & 5.78312 & 6.29811 & 6.74499 & 7.14644 & 7.51462 \\
 4 & 6.00926 & 6.55128 & 7.01770 & 7.43438 & 7.81498 \\
 5 & 6.15621 & 6.71544 & 7.19444 & 7.62104 & 8.00982 \\
 6 & 6.25884 & 6.82996 & 7.31772 & 7.75125 & 8.14578 \\
 7 & 6.33436 & 6.91418 & 7.40837 & 7.84702 & 8.24580 \\
 8 & 6.39206 & 6.97851 & 7.47762 & 7.92019 & 8.32224 \\
 9 & 6.43724 & 7.02892 & 7.53191 & 7.97759 & 8.38223 \\
 10 & 6.47308 & 7.06899 & 7.57512 & 8.02331 & 8.43005 \\
 11 & 6.50154 & 7.10094 & 7.60967 & 8.05994 & 8.46842 \\
 12 & 6.52390 & 7.12622 & 7.63714 & 8.08915 & 8.49909 \\
 13 & 6.54100 & 7.14581 & 7.65858 & 8.11209 & 8.52328 \\
 14 & 6.55345 & 7.16041 & 7.67477 & 8.12956 & 8.54183 \\
 15 & 6.56171 & 7.17053 & 7.68629 & 8.14220 & 8.55540 \\
 16 & 6.56616 & 7.17662 & 7.69360 & 8.15049 & 8.56452 \\
 17 & 6.56713 & 7.17903 & 7.69710 & 8.15486 & 8.56962 \\
 18 & 6.56491 & 7.17811 & 7.69714 & 8.15568 & 8.57109 \\
 19 & 6.55978 & 7.17414 & 7.69404 & 8.15328 & 8.56927 \\
 20 & 6.55200 & 7.16740 & 7.68808 & 8.14795 & 8.56447
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

To give you an idea of the complexity of the formulae for the simplest case
$$L_4=2 a\, \int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2} \sqrt{\sin (t) \tan (t)+\cos (t) \cot (t)}\,dt$$
$$L_4=a\frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{16 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{7/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}\,G_{5,5}^{5,5}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6},1,\frac{4}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{12},\frac{5}{12},\frac{7}{12},\frac{3}{4},\frac{13}{12}
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

Comment: This does not look like a numerical approximation...? Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage. For $k=1$, I gave the decimal representation of the nasty Meijer G-functions. For $k\neq 1$, numerical integration.

Comment: You've given the numbers, but not a way to do the approximation myself. To use the old adage: You've given me fish, but I still don't know how to catch any myself.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage. I added the formula for the simplest case. All other have the same shape with more and more coefficients.